# iOS 8 Extension user info

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, ios-app-extension

I am creating an action extension in iOS8 beta, I am trying to pass some values across to from the host app to the extension using the UserInfo Dict of NSExtensionItem. However this I am not getting any values passed over

Host.m

```
NSItemProvider *item = [[NSItemProvider alloc] init];

NSExtensionItem *requestItem = [[NSExtensionItem alloc] init];

requestItem.attachments = @[item];
requestItem.userInfo =  @{@"action":@"my action",@"title":@"My title"};


UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[requestItem] applicationActivities:nil];
```

Extension

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Verify that we have a valid NSExtensionItem
NSExtensionItem *dictItem = [self.extensionContext.inputItems firstObject];

if(!dictItem){
  return;
}
self.actionLabel.text =  [dictItem.userInfo valueForKey:@"action"];
self.titleLabel.text =  [dictItem.userInfo valueForKey:@"title"];
}
```

It would be great to see if anyone else has got this working or if it is an issue with the beta

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24056024/2446155

Comment: ios8 is under NDA (except swift) & you cannot discuss it outside apple dev forums until the beta is over.

Comment: Incorrect - "Further, Apple agrees that You will not be bound by the foregoing confidentiality terms with regard to technical information about pre-release Apple Software and services disclosed by Apple at WWDC (Apple’s Worldwide Developers Conference), except that You may not post screen shots, write public reviews or redistribute any pre-release Apple Software or services."

https://developer.apple.com/programs/terms/ios/standard/ios_program_standard_agreement_20140602.pdf