# iOS 8 Share extension loadItemForTypeIdentifier:options:completionHandler: completion closure not executing

Tags: share, swift, ios8, ios-app-extension

I'm using the 
loadItemForTypeIdentifier:options:completionHandler: method on an NSItemProvider object to extract a url from Safari via a Share extension in iOS 8.

In Objective-C, this code and works and the block runs.

```
[itemProvider loadItemForTypeIdentifier:(@"public.url" options:nil completionHandler:^(NSURL *url, NSError *error) {
    //My code
}];
```

In Swift, it looks very similar, however the closure doesn't run. Also,  `itemProvider.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier("public.url")` returns `YES` so there must be a valid object to parse the url from inside the `itemProvider`.

```
itemProvider.loadItemForTypeIdentifier("public.url", options: nil, completionHandler: { (urlItem, error) in
    //My code
})
```

The Info.plist NSExtension portion is exactly the same for both Objective-C and Swift version and looks like this:

```
<key>NSExtension</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExtensionActivationRule</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsWebURLWithMaxCount</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
        </dict>
        <key>NSExtensionPointName</key>
        <string>com.apple.share-services</string>
        <key>NSExtensionPointVersion</key>
        <string>1.0</string>
    </dict>
    <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.apple.share-services</string>
    <key>NSExtensionMainStoryboard</key>
    <string>MainInterface</string>
</dict>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I hate to be the one to say it but is this not violating the dev terms and conditions? NDAs on new releases etc.

Comment: @ScottMcGready you must've missed the memo, but they've relaxed the NDA quite a bit. Google it.

Comment: I just took the view of, it's apple- it's probably under NDA. Glad they're opening up a bit more though. Need to read the docs now they've been updated.

Comment: Seeing a similar issue in Objective-C in the latest Beta where the block isn't being called. Anyone else having similar issues?

Comment: Make sure that you don't call complete method:
`[self.extensionContext completeRequestReturningItems:items completionHandler:nil]` till your share process will be completed. Call it in loadItemForTypeIdentifier completion handler for example.

Answer (score 12):

call

```
self.extensionContext!.completeRequestReturningItems([], completionHandler: nil)
```

at the end of completionHandler instead of calling it at the end of didSelectPost()

Comment: Perfect. Should be accepted. Works on iOS 8 (on simulator)

Answer (score 6):

Since completeRequestReturningItems must be called after all completionHandlers are called back, below is what I do.

```
 let group = dispatch_group_create()

    for item: AnyObject in self.extensionContext!.inputItems {
        let inputItem = item as! NSExtensionItem
        for provider: AnyObject in inputItem.attachments! {
            let itemProvider = provider as! NSItemProvider
            if itemProvider.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier("public.url") {
                dispatch_group_enter(group)
                itemProvider.loadItemForTypeIdentifier("public.url", options: nil, completionHandler: {
                    (result: NSSecureCoding!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                    //...
                    dispatch_group_leave(group)
                });
            }
            if itemProvider.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier(kUTTypeImage as String) {
                dispatch_group_enter(group)
                itemProvider.loadItemForTypeIdentifier(kUTTypeImage as String, options: nil, completionHandler: { (result, error) -> Void in
                    if let resultURL = result as? NSURL {
                        if let image = UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOfURL: resultURL)!) {
                            // ...
                        }
                    }
                    dispatch_group_leave(group)
                });
            }
        }
    }
    dispatch_group_notify(group,dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), {
        self.extensionContext!.completeRequestReturningItems([], completionHandler: nil)
    })
```

Comment: too complicated answer. It can be done in a very simpler way.

Comment: I wish so too. It would be great if you can advise if you have anything in mind.

Answer (score 4):

I take no credit for this, but have a look at how this guy did it: https://github.com/oguzbilgener/SendToInstapaper/blob/master/ShareExtension/SendingViewController.swift

Answer (score 1):

I was never managed completionHandler to work properly for Share extension with no user interface (in such case extension's class is a subclass on NSObject).

Despite the `[itemProvider hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier:(NSString *)kUTTypeURL]` returns `YES` the completionHandler is never called both on the device or simulator.

After trying different approaches I ended up with workaround based on javascript passing URL back to extension (sorry as I use ObjC not Swift for my example).

`Info.plist` NSExtension portion:

```
<key>NSExtension</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExtensionActivationRule</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsWebURLWithMaxCount</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
        </dict>
        <key>NSExtensionJavaScriptPreprocessingFile</key>
        <string>Action</string>
    </dict>
    <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.apple.services</string>
    <key>NSExtensionPrincipalClass</key>
    <string>ActionRequestHandler</string>
</dict>
```

---

Javascript `Action.js` file:

```
var Action = function() {};
Action.prototype = {
    run: function(arguments) {
        arguments.completionFunction({ "currentURL" : window.location.href })
    },
    finalize: function(arguments) {
    }
};
var ExtensionPreprocessingJS = new Action
```

---

`ActionRequestHandler.h` header file:

```objc
@interface ActionRequestHandler : NSObject <NSExtensionRequestHandling>

@end
```

---

`ActionRequestHandler.m` based on default Action extension template:

```objc
#import "ActionRequestHandler.h"
#import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>

@interface ActionRequestHandler ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSExtensionContext *extensionContext;

@end

@implementation ActionRequestHandler

- (void)beginRequestWithExtensionContext:(NSExtensionContext *)context {
    // Do not call super in an Action extension with no user interface
    self.extensionContext = context;

    BOOL found = NO;

    // Find the item containing the results from the JavaScript preprocessing.
    for (NSExtensionItem *item in self.extensionContext.inputItems) {
        for (NSItemProvider *itemProvider in item.attachments) {
            if ([itemProvider hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier:(NSString *)kUTTypePropertyList]) {
                [itemProvider loadItemForTypeIdentifier:(NSString *)kUTTypePropertyList options:nil completionHandler:^(NSDictionary *dictionary, NSError *error) {
                    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
                        [self itemLoadCompletedWithPreprocessingResults:dictionary[NSExtensionJavaScriptPreprocessingResultsKey]];
                    }];
                }];
                found = YES;
            }
            break;
        }
        if (found) {
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!found) {
        // We did not find anything - signal that we're done
        [self.extensionContext completeRequestReturningItems:@[] completionHandler:nil];
        // Don't hold on to this after we finished with it
        self.extensionContext = nil;
    }
}

- (void)itemLoadCompletedWithPreprocessingResults:(NSDictionary *)javaScriptPreprocessingResults
{
    // Get the URL
    if ([javaScriptPreprocessingResults[@"currentURL"] length] != 0) {
        NSLog(@"*** URL: %@", javaScriptPreprocessingResults[@"currentURL"]);
    }

    // Signal that we're done
    [self.extensionContext completeRequestReturningItems:@[] completionHandler:nil];
    // Don't hold on to this after we finished with it
    self.extensionContext = nil;
}

@end
```

Hope it will help somebody to save couple of hours struggling with the completionHandler issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue in my iOS 12.1. I'm calling

```
loadItemForTypeIdentifier:kUTTypeData
```

instead of `kUTTypeImage` etc. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have been battled with this issue on and off for the last few weeks, and have finally found the issue. I has nothing to do with Objective C or Swift, it just appears to be a bug in Apple's code.

It seems that (as at iOS 8.0), the completion block is only called if you are using your own `UIViewController` subclass. If you are using a subclass of `SLComposeServiceViewController`, then the completion block is not called.

This is really annoying, as by default XCode creates you a `ShareViewController` with a subclass of `SLComposeServiceViewController`. To work around this issue, you just have to modify ShareViewController to inherit from `UIViewController`. This will still give access to the `extensionContext` property, but you'll obviously lose all of nice standard functionality and will have to implement your UI from scratch.

I've filed a radar with Apple, but have not had a reply yet. Hopefully this will be fixed in a future update.

Comment: Not true, see pJes2's answer

Comment: How is this 'not true'? pJes2's answer does exactly what I say here, subclassing UIViewController rather than SLComposeServiceViewController. i.e. `class SendingViewController: UIViewController `

Comment: The work around mentioned here (subclassing your own `UIViewController`) is basically the same solution proposed by pJes2. Without having to rely on someone else's code.