# iOS Share Extension - handle screenshot data

Tags: ios, swift, ios8-share-extension, slcomposeviewcontroller

I am trying to receive screenshot data from my Share Extension. I am running iOS 15.5.

```
override func didSelectPost() {
   if let extensionItems = self.extensionContext?.inputItems as? [NSExtensionItem]  {
      let attachments     = extensionItems.first?.attachments ?? []
      let imageType       = UTType.image.identifier
      
      for provider in attachments {
         if provider.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier(imageType) {
            print("It is an image")

            // this seems only to handle media from photos
            provider.loadFileRepresentation(forTypeIdentifier: imageType) { (unsafeFileUrl, error) in
               print("We have the image")
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

**Observed behaviour**

- When sharing a photo from the Photos App, the didSelectPost() method works as expected.
- When capturing an image from the Share button, I can see the print("It is an image"), however I cannot access the actual image data.

**What I have tried**

- I have tried to access the provider's content using loadItem and loadDataRepresentation, neither trigger a print statement.
- Other StackOverflow question suggest using

**Questions that have not resolved my issue**

- [iOS Share Extension crashes when sharing from iOS 11 Screenshot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44498932/ios-share-extension-crashes-when-sharing-from-ios-11-screenshot)

  - Cannot get data to cast as UIImage. loadFileRepresentation, loadItem, and loadDataRepresentation do not provide anything (the closure does not trigger a print statement)
- [cannot open/read image via share extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46987686/cannot-open-read-image-via-share-extension)

  - Similarly I cannot get the "load" methods to trigger to access anything from the Screen Shot.

**Expected behaviour**

- I get the Screen Shot image data which I can save to disc.

**Queries**

- Why can I not access the Screen Shot data?
- How do I access the screen shot data?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. The data from the screenshot is actually a UIImage, so  this worked for me:

```
                         //sometimes the item is a UIImage (i.e., screenshots)
                         itemProvider.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: UTType.image.identifier) { item, error in
                             if let image = item as? UIImage {
                                 DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
                                     guard let self = self else { return }
                                     self.imageView.image =   image
                                 }
                                 return
                             }

                         }
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to comment. I've just tried the code and for some reason the "loadItem" closure isn't executing..!  Works absolutely fine if I send a URL, which I can load with .loadFileRepresentation. This has been killing me for weeks.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, it doesn't get to the part of the code where it parses the data received. I already tried with breakpoints, but it seems like it's not even loading the extension whenever I try to call it from the screenshot view. Btw, I'm using iOS 16...

Comment: If `loadItem(forTypeIdentifier:)` is not being called (after taking a screenshot), then you need to make sure you're calling `completeRequest(returningItems:completionHandler:)` at the right time. This answer explains it in detail: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24235954/ios-8-share-extension-loaditemfortypeidentifieroptionscompletionhandler-compl/31238670#31238670

Comment: Thanks, worked for me! Wondering why canLoadObject(UIImage) doesn't work!

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the activation rules to the info.plist of the share sheet:

```
        <dict>
            <key>NSExtensionActivationRule</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsImageWithMaxCount</key>
                <integer>1</integer>
                <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsText</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
```

Comment: I have the following activation rule, so I can capture URLs and images:

`SUBQUERY (
   extensionItems,
   $extensionItem,
   SUBQUERY (
      $extensionItem.attachments,
      $attachment,
      ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.image"
   ).@count == 1
).@count == 1
||
SUBQUERY (
    extensionItems,
    $extensionItem,
    SUBQUERY (
        $extensionItem.attachments,
        $attachment,
        ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.url"
    ).@count == 1
).@count == 1`

Comment: Sorry, formatting isn't great on comments!