# iOS 8 Share Extension loadPreviewView

Tags: ios, ios8

In iOS8 extensions, specifically the share extension, has anyone been able to override the loadPreviewView method to supply a custom preview view?  I created one by returning a 50x50 UIView with a UIIMageView subview, but it shows up outside of the extension view (too far right) and it does not push the textView in the share extension over to the left.  If anyone has customized this, please provide sample code!  Thanks

Comment: Check it : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24056024/sharing-extension-in-ios8-beta?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Yep, I could get it working using width & height constraints. If I set a size and a mask it would not show up properly.

Here is a sample code:

```
- (UIView *)loadPreviewView {
UIView * previewView = [super loadPreviewView];

if (previewView == nil) {
    previewView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    [previewView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[previewView(90)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(previewView)]];
    [previewView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[previewView(90)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(previewView)]];
}

return previewView;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can derive from `UIImageView` and provide an implementation for `intrinsicContentSize`:

```
@interface MyImageView : UIImageView

@end

@implementation MyImageView

-(CGSize)intrinsicContentSize {
  return CGSizeMake(70, 70);
}

@end
```

It's detailed in this WWDC session: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/224/?time=334

It's likely you'll also want to configure you view like so:

```
view.clipsToBounds = YES;
view.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
```